# Bootstrap 3 responsiveness on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for a project and I am having difficulty in collapsing the navbar at the right time. I have not edited the stock bootstrap code using LESS so the default collapse if 768px. I have tested my own project against the Bootstrap website, getbootstrap.com and theirs seems to be the same, however when I view it on my Nexus 4 their navbar collapses and mine doesn't.

How've they got it to do this? It collapses on desktop at 768px and on my phone it's more zoomed in and collapses, however on my website it is not collapsed on mobile..?

Comment: Do you add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  in the head of your page?

Comment: @SlawaEremkin No I have not. Do I need that?

Comment: @SlawaEremkin - I added it and it has worked. Thank you very much. Write this as an answer and I will mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout, do you add this code?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

More information you can find here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag